# Deploying Qt program to raspberry pi

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, embedded, listener

I have been tasked to develop a piece of hardware at work which is controlled remotely by a raspberry pi Zero. A server program made in Qt will run on the pi and the client program will connect to the pi via a router or ad-hoc network. The qt client program (run on a laptop) will send commands to the pi server to make it interface with the hardware, obtain data and then send results back.

This thing will run on batteries, so I need to keep things minimal. I plan on using Raspbian as this the most supported. As soon as I turn the pi on, I want it to boot up to command line and start the listening server without the OS GUI/desktop.

Is this a feasible way of implementing the listening server? Are there better ways to do this?

I haven't really done this before with a pi so my question/situation is a bit vague, apologies!

Comment: Yes, your design idea seems feasible. You can add a script to `init.d` folder on linux to autostart your server app. However, it looks like you want to be to support a GUI on the server. For that, you will need to at least run a gui server.

Comment: Not sure but this document might be of help: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html